# Globally set the justification in a framed box

Tags: horizontal-alignment, listings, boxes, framed

I want to show the text from a Python Interpreter in a Windows console. This should be plain text (like you see in a command line terminal). I also want to show Python code snippets with highlighting. To do this, I set my default listing style for coloring (`\lstset`) and then created a custom listing style for command line terminal output (`\lstdefinestyle`).

When I try to use a framed box to show the terminal output, I find that it tries to fully justify the lines and adds extra spaces between words. How do I globally set all framed boxes to be left justified so I don't have to justify each box? Here is what I did:

```
\documentclass[openright,12pt]{book}
%Include Packages
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{listings} %code snippets
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{framed} %console output displays
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{headings}

%Syntax Coloring for code snippets
\lstset{
  belowcaptionskip=1\baselineskip,
  breaklines=true,
  frame=l,
  xleftmargin=\parindent,
  language=Python,
  showstringspaces=false,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
  keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{green!40!black},
  commentstyle=\itshape\color{mygray},
  identifierstyle=\color{blue},
  stringstyle=\color{orange},
  numbers=left,
  numbersep=15pt, 
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
}

%Syntax coloring for inline code at the console
\lstdefinestyle{consolePy}{
  breaklines=true,
  language=Python,
  showstringspaces=false,
  xleftmargin=0pt,
  frame=none,
  numbers=none,
  identifierstyle=\ttfamily\color{black},
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\color{black},  
  commentstyle=\ttfamily\color{black},
  stringstyle=\ttfamily\color{black},
  keywordstyle=\ttfamily\color{black}
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{framed}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=consolePy]
>>> MyName = “Jason”
>>> print MyName
Jason
>>> MyAge = 30
>>> print 'My name is', MyName, 'and I'm', MyAge, 'years old.'
My name is Jason and I’m 30 years old.
\end{lstlisting}
\end{framed}
\end{document}
```

I would show a screen capture of the result but I'm new so I can't post images. Just know that the result is my text showing large white spaces in the framed listing. Thank you for any guidance you can provide!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I'm sorry about that. I just changed the OP to include a working example. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I can't see any differences. The package `framed` doesn't influence the justification.

Comment: The following expression is justified and thus has huge white space when I print to pdf: >>> print 'My name is', MyName, 'and I'm', MyAge, 'years old.'

Comment: @JasonLillywhite You *can* include an image; just use the interface and remove the `!` that's added in front of the link; a user with enough rep will add it back. Does adding `columns=fullflexible` to your `\lstset` help?

Comment: @egreg - That is the ticket! My snippet now is left justified. Thank you!

Comment: @JasonLillywhite Actually there is another problem: the double quotes won't appear.

Comment: @egreg: Can you provide a small answer? The double qoutes need a double input: `MyName = “"Jason”"`

Comment: @egreg Could you write your comments here up as an answer please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the option

```
columns=fullflexible
```

so that letters are stuck together as in normal typewriter type.

Note also that you should use the dumb quotes `"` rather than `“`, because `listings` doesn't really understand UTF-8.

```
\documentclass[openright,12pt]{book}
%Include Packages
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{listings} %code snippets
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{framed} %console output displays
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{headings}

%Syntax Coloring for code snippets
\lstset{
  belowcaptionskip=1\baselineskip,
  breaklines=true,
  frame=l,
  xleftmargin=\parindent,
  language=Python,
  showstringspaces=false,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
  keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{green!40!black},
  commentstyle=\itshape\color{mygray},
  identifierstyle=\color{blue},
  stringstyle=\color{orange},
  numbers=left,
  numbersep=15pt, 
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
}

%Syntax coloring for inline code at the console
\lstdefinestyle{consolePy}{
  breaklines=true,
  language=Python,
  showstringspaces=false,
  xleftmargin=0pt,
  frame=none,
  numbers=none,
  identifierstyle=\ttfamily\color{black},
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\color{black},  
  commentstyle=\ttfamily\color{black},
  stringstyle=\ttfamily\color{black},
  keywordstyle=\ttfamily\color{black},
  columns=fullflexible, % <--- added!
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{framed}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=consolePy]
>>> MyName = "Jason"
>>> print MyName
Jason
>>> MyAge = 30
>>> print 'My name is', MyName, 'and I'm', MyAge, 'years old.'
My name is Jason and I’m 30 years old.
\end{lstlisting}
\end{framed}
\end{document}
```

[image]